# how to find the index of a character in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a code that finds index of a character in a string. This is I wrote so far.
It shows me 3 two times. The first 'o' is indeed 3, and there are two o. But why does it give me 3 instead of 11?

```
my_string = 'I love my dogs!'
for char in my_string:
    if char == 'o':
        print(my_string.index(char))
```

Comment: [`str.index`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) gives you the *first* index of a given character, the loop isn't really helping you at all here.

Comment: Did you read docs on `str.index` ?

Comment: so how can I get all indexes? I am really new to python

Comment: See my comment.